# Using a loop in attributes:txt to cycle through multiple pages

Tags: loops, web-scraping, imacros

I'm attempting to use this IMacros to click through and download a large number of real estate sales.  The "TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2" is a button that I click to bring up more listings, and is one of those menus where you click 1, 2, 3,...etc. to get to different pages.  Is there a way to set up a loop to cycle through these pages?  (the txt tag is what does it.)

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://chicagotribune.public-record.com/realestate/search/cook
TAG POS=1 TYPE=FIELDSET FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=TXT:Required<SP>Search<SP>ParametersInput<SP>Date<SP>(mm/dd/yyyy*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:sdate CONTENT=01/01/2003
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:edate CONTENT=12/31/2005
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:submit
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:"dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:2
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:"dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure! At first play the following macro in usual mode:

```
URL GOTO=http://chicagotribune.public-record.com/realestate/search/cook
TAG POS=1 TYPE=FIELDSET FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=TXT:Required<SP>Search<SP>ParametersInput<SP>Date<SP>(mm/dd/yyyy*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:sdate CONTENT=01/01/2003
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:edate CONTENT=12/31/2005
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:theForm ATTR=NAME:submit
```

and then play this one in loop mode:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:"dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
SET page EVAL({{!LOOP}}+1)
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{page}}
```